# Data pass tableview cell to tab bar view controller in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am new to swift

The tableview contain multiple images working fine this the code :

```
             override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

                    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Media", for: indexPath)as! MediaCustomTableViewCell               
                    let row = indexPath.row                       
                    let media = Mediainfo[row] as MediaEvent                
                    cell.DisplayDate.text = media.date                
                    cell.DisplayName.text = media.eventName                       
                    cell.selectionStyle = .none                        
                    cell.DisplayImage.downloadImageFrom(link:media.bannerImages, contentMode: UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFit)

                    return cell
                }


                override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
                    return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
                }


                override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
                {                    
                    let media = Mediainfo[(indexPath.row)] as MediaEvent                        
                    let ImageStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)                      
                    let  ImageController = ImageStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IMAGESCOL")as!ImagesCollectionViewController
```

Here I'm passing an image to a collection view but its not working:

```
                    ImageController.RecivedData1 = media.bannerImages                                            
                    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)                      
                    let tabcontroller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IMAGEVID") as! UITabBarController

                    navigationController?.pushViewController(tabcontroller, animated: true)

                }
```

After select any image in tableview cell image should show at tab bar with collection view. I am showing images and videos categories wise I can use tab bar controller

Data pass to:

**Tableview ---> tab bar controller ===>  2 collection views**

How can pass the tableview images data to collection using tab bar controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code

```
let ImageStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let ImageController = ImageStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IMAGESCOL") as! ImagesCollectionViewController
ImageController.RecivedData1 = media.bannerImages
```

These codes do nothing is expected, because you declare an `ImageController`, but you don't use/present it.

So, according to the context, I assume that you have a `UITabBarController` in `Main.storyboard`, and the `UITabBarController` has two `UIViewController`, and one is `ImageController`. If I were right, you could try codes below:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let tabBarController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "IMAGEVID") as! UITabBarController

// You should access the `imageController` through your `tabBarController`, 
// not instantiate it from storyboard.
if let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers, 
   let imageController = viewControllers.first as? ImageController {
    imageController.recivedData1 = media.bannerImages
}

navigationController?.pushViewController(tabBarController, animated: true)
```

Another suggestion is you should use camel case to name your properties. For more details, you can refer to [this style guideline](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide#naming).

Comment: @ mrfour how can send data to tab view controller second view controller, I can try viewControllers.first as viewControllers.second it's not working

Comment: let imageController1 = viewControllers[1] as? VideosCollectionViewController  I did this it's working fine bro....

Comment: In my opinion `let imageController1 = viewControllers[1] as? VideosCollectionViewController` should work. Please check whether viewControllers had at least two viewControllers. If it does, maybe you can use break point  to `po viewControllers[1]` to see what it is?